# How to exclude sent mail in rule for Outlook

Tags: outlook

I've got a form sending email via my own SMTP. I want to create a rule to move it to a folder, but the rule picks up the sent mail too.

How can I force the rule to ignore my sent box and only show the received message?

[I suspect this has something to do with threaded messaging - I'd prefer not to turn it off for my whole account to solve this problem]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA macro where you can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class where you can handle only incoming emails and put them into a specific depending on the condition defined. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

In the event handler you may get the instance of the item received and call the `Move` method which moves the the item to a folder.